# AirPods get "stuck" very often on Catalina. Killing bluetoothd does not help

Tags: catalina, bluetooth, airpods

Running Catalina on a rMB 12 early 2016.

Sometimes AirPods (2nd gen) get stuck and I cannot disconnect them from my Macboook. *I've tried to killall bt daemon from terminal* but that did not work; also I cannot figure out how to bootstrap `com.apple.bluetoothUIServer` with launchctl (maybe that will help?)

```
% launchctl list |grep -i blu  
-   0   com.apple.bluetoothUIServer
```

Also (15:35 at the time of running ps):

```
% sudo ps aux | grep -i blu
root             24233   0.0  0.1  4341256   7648   ??  Ss    1:25PM   0:23.19 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
root             26058   0.0  0.1  4336844   8072   ??  Us    3:33PM   0:00.07 /usr/sbin/bluetoothaudiod <-- This one seems to restart randomly
```

[Here's an imgur video of the issue](https://i.imgur.com/YuL2GSx.mp4)

Rebooting the computer works but this happens quite often and would like to avoid restarting the whole computer just to fix bluetooth.

Anyone know what can I try to redo the whole bluetooth thing and reconnect my airpods? Other devices are sometimes affected, sometimes not.

### Steps attempted:

- Killing the BT daemon.
- Putting them in the case and closing the case and try to move them out of range. They still show there.
- Forgetting/Removing them. This only caused the behaviour stated below in "Edit for @Thinkr"
- Reset the BT module through Shift+Opt+Debug

### Edit for @Thinkr

I've removed them from the System Preferences, and then they got reattached automatically. Also, now it shows on the taskbar icon only with their MAC address and they're requesting a code? That's very odd.
(PS: System Preferences also seems to hang when it reads the AirPods as some sort of unknown BT device).

[image]

### Edit for @Allan:

Here you can see the MX mouse getting 'cloned' several times. None of these options I can pair. BT module going bonkers?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting the bluetooth module? Press and hold Shift+Option and click the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Then, release the keys and go to Debug and click "Reset the Bluetooth module".

Comment: Hello @Thinkr! Thanks for your help. I forgot about that option. I did it but still in the same situation. It's like the Bluetooth UI is stuck for some reason, and I cannot figure out how to restart it.

Comment: Is this happening with other AirPods? Have you also tried forgetting and repairing the AirPods?

Comment: @Thinkr hello! I've edited my question to add more info about your recommendation.

Comment: Just to clarify, ***you cannot disconnect your AirPods from your Mac,*** correct?  Do they work otherwise?  What if you put them in the case and/or move them out of range?  What happens then?

Comment: Hello @Allan! Thanks for your input. Correct, I cannot disconnect them from the BT menu on the taskbar. They do not work. Neither does my BT Mouse after I also tested forgetting it. However yesterday it was only the AirPods.

I've put them in their case and tried moving out of range and the item is still there on the menu. But tbh, I live in an flat and I do get reception almost everywhere.

Comment: When you say your AirPods and BT mouse don’t work, you mean you cannot hear music/calls, control playback etc. and the mouse doesn’t respond at all?  The next step to take is try pairing them (the mouse at least) with a different machine.  Do the AirPods work with an iPhone/iPad?  Lastly, try booting into Safe Mode and see if these things work.  Oh…are you using a Magic wireless keyboard?

Comment: @Allan: Yessir; it's as if BT module was completely dead. AirPods work perfectly with iPhone. BT Mouse is also paired with the iPhone and it works. I can try pairing a BT apple keyboard I have.

Comment: No need.  Just see what happens in Safe Mode to rule out any 3rd party ketxt/software.  I (feat that I) know where this is going, but we need to be through

Comment: @Allan: Magic Keyboard works ok. I'm actually typing this comment from it. BT mouse however, it's showing me 3 versions of the same mouse to pair for some reason. My suspicion is that the BT module / daemon is just crazy. Not sure how I can restart the whole thing from Terminal without having to restart the whole computer.

Comment: There’s more than “the bluetooth daemon”. BT is part of the AirPort adapter and there are several kexts related to this.  A reboot may very well fix things.  Still want to see results of Safe Mode, though.

Comment: @Allan: I agree with you, rebooting the laptop is what has been fixing the issue for me since this started (with Catalina), but my aim would be to exhaust as many options possible before having to resort to restarting the laptop. Mostly because I have a lot of work ongoing, some jobs that are currently running and downloads/uploads happening. Of course I can pause many of these things, but I am very interested in learning to resolve it without having to restart the whole computer. Is there a way to renice/restart the Airport adapter?

Comment: Not without losing the connection to your keyboard.  You have to unload the kext then load it back.  Once you unload it, you’ll have no keyboard.  Since this affects 2 out of the 3 devices you have, it could be an issue with a conflicting app/kext; thus the Safe Mode test.

Comment: @Allan: Hello again! I'm not using a BT keyboard. Just the one from the Macbook. I've looked up the kext files on my Macbook, not sure which one I'm looking for. I found a `IOBluetoothFamily.kext` but I cannot unload it becase it's in use.

Comment: Did you try Safe Mode?  It looks like you have the Logitech drivers loaded and it quite possibly can be conflicting

Comment: Hello @Allan! By safe mode you mean rebooting the laptop?